# ERROR : Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-code, null

ERROR : Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
ERROR :  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.

Ping solution to this error except clean project and npm reinstall and am not running it in expo.

Comment: Contributor should add details of research effort so that the question is clear and and useful.

Comment: same issue here for two days without any working solution

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for the past two days.
I did the following steps to solve the problem:

1- According to this solution for the issue started on November 4 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210
I changed my react-native project version package.json from 0.66.3 to 0.66.5

2- Then I deleted the node_modules

3- Run yarn install

4- Run cd android && ./gradlew clean

Then my project worked smoothly again.